# how to put a if condition in a object var

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is to put a if condition between two arrays. In my form, there is some inputs that doesnt need to be validate if his parent div is still hidden. (my form has separated div, some hidden).

```
$validate = new Validate;
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
                'nom' => array('required' => true),
                'prenom' => array('required' => true),
                'adresse' => array('required' => true),
                'ville' => array('required' => true),
                'codepostal' => array('required' => true),
                'depuis' => array('required' => true),
                'telephone' => array('required' => true),
                'loyer' => array('required' => true),
                'valeur' => array('required' => true),
                'solde' => array('required' => true),
```

so, for exemple I want to do

```
$validate = new Validate;
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
                'nom' => array('required' => true),
                'prenom' => array('required' => true),
                'adresse' => array('required' => true),
                'ville' => array('required' => true),
                'codepostal' => array('required' => true)));

            if (Input::get('myinput') == 'on') {
                  'depuis' => array('required' => true),
                  'telephone' => array('required' => true),
            }

    $validation .= $validate->check($_POST, array(      
                'loyer' => array('required' => true),
                'valeur' => array('required' => true),
                'solde' => array('required' => true)));
```

But yeah, you guessed it..it doesnt work that easily..any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright so, after some research here is what I found out the best :

First, you need to play with array_merge();

For example,

```
$validate = new Validate;
        $infoproValidate = array(
            'nom' => array('required' => true),
            'prenom' => array('required' => true),
            'adresse' => array('required' => true),
            'ville' => array('required' => true),
            'codepostal' => array('required' => true),
            'depuis' => array('required' => true),
            'telephone' => array('required' => true),
            'loyer' => array('required' => true),
            'valeur' => array('required' => true),
            'solde' => array('required' => true),
            'employeur' => array('required' => true),
            'fonction' => array('required' => true),
            'adressePro' => array('required' => true),
            'villePro' => array('required' => true),
            'telephonePro' => array('required' => true),
            'temps' => array('required' => true),
            'salaire' => array('required' => true),
            'concessionnaire' => array('required' => true),
            'marque' => array('required' => true),
            'modele' => array('required' => true),
            'annee' => array('required' => true),
            'kilometrage' => array('required' => true),
            'prix' => array('required' => true));

        if(Input::get('depuis') == '2 ans et moins') {
            $infoAncien = array(
                'adresseAncien' => array('required' => true),
                'codepostalAncien' => array('required' => true),
                'villeAncien' => array('required' => true),
                'telephoneAncien' => array('required' => true)
            );
        } else {
            $infoAncien = array();
        }

        $resultArr = array_merge((array)$infoproValidate, (array)$infoAncien);
```

I hope this can help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
       $validate = new Validate;

        $inputarr[]=array();
        $inputarr[]=array(
                    'nom' => array('required' => true),
                    'prenom' => array('required' => true),
                    'adresse' => array('required' => true),
                    'ville' => array('required' => true),
                    'codepostal' => array('required' => true));
                  );
        if (Input::get('myinput') == 'on') {
        $inputarr[]=array(
                  'depuis' => array('required' => true),
              'telephone' => array('required' => true),
           );
        }

       $inputarr[]= array(      
            'loyer' => array('required' => true),
            'valeur' => array('required' => true),
            'solde' => array('required' => true)
       );

       $validation = $validate->check($_POST, $inputarr);
```

Comment: Well hum, my $inputarr now hold only 3 arrays. Loyer, valeur and solde

Comment: $inputarr[] this is correct i edited my post check it